# Conversion string error

Tags: vb.net, debugging

Whenever I try and run my program I keep getting an error that states

> "Conversion from string "59 60 65 75" to type 'Double' is not valid."

I am getting my data from a file called scores.txt which holds the integers 59, 60, 65, 75. I'm not quite sure how to correct this issue, VB has suggested a few things such as making sure the value being less than infinity(clearly it is) and make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type.(this one I am unsure of on how to debug) Any suggestions? Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnanalyze.Click


        Dim scores() As String =
            IO.File.ReadAllLines("scores.txt")
        Dim intdata(scores.length - 1) As Double 'declare an array of type double to store the data of text file

        Dim mean As Double
        Dim sdeviation As Double = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To scores.length - 1
            intdata(i) = CDbl(scores(i))

        Next
        mean = intdata.Average 'mean is the average of the numbers in the collection
        For j As Integer = 0 To intdata.Length - 1
            sdeviation = +Math.Pow(intdata(j) - mean, 2)

        Next
        sdeviation = sdeviation / (intdata.Length)
        sdeviation = Math.Sqrt(sdeviation)
        lblmean.text = FormatNumber(mean)
        lblsd.text = FormatNumber(sdeviation)
        lblnumofexams.text = scores.length
        Dim query = From score In scores
                    Let Sscore = score
                    Let grade = getGrade(score, mean, sdeviation)
                    Select Sscore, grade
        dvgoutput.datasource = query.tolist
        dvgoutput.currentcell = Nothing
        dvgoutput.columns("Sscore").headertext = "score"
        dvgoutput.columns("grade").headertext = "grade"




    End Sub
    Public Function getGrade(ByVal ES, ByVal m, ByVal s) As String
        If ES >= m + (1.5 * s) Then
            Return "A"
        End If
        If m + (0.5 * s) < +ES And ES < m + (1.5 * s) Then
            Return "B"
        End If

        If m - (0.5 * s) <= ES And ES < m + (0.5 * s) Then
            Return "C"
        End If

        If m - (1.5 * s) <= ES And ES < +m - (0.5 * s) Then
            Return "D"
        End If

        If ES < m - (1.5 * s) Then
            Return "F"
        End If
        Return ""
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I am getting an error at this line " intdata(i) = CDbl(scores(i))"

Comment: It sounds like it is reading in all the numbers and not just one.  And therefore can't convert it.  Figure out how to feed it one number at a time.

Comment: What if you have one score on each line of the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have one score per line in the text file.